# Persisting a large data set in PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, windows-services, http-request, persistent-storage

I work for a government organization that develops databases slowly ;-) I need a way to retrieve and filter up to 1.2 gigs of data efficiently as a short-term solution while the database is being developed. Thread safety is not an issue as the data is read only. The data represents an archive of highway incidents/events.

- I don't want to read 1.2 gigs of data from disk into memory for each HTTP request.
- I don't want to use the PHP session because this stores data on disk and (as far as I know) only saves data for a single browser session. This would result in maintaining a copy of 1.2 gigs of data for each session.
- I **do** want the data to persist in memory (for performance reasons) and be accessible by all requests processed by the PHP script.
- The data is read from disk in JSON format and will likely be stored in a PHP associative array.
- I am developing on a Windows server.

I've considered developing a .NET Windows Service and connecting to it using CURL to retrieve the data. I've read about running a PHP script as a Windows service. A great solution might be utilizing persistent memory in the PHP script processing the HTTP requests, but the only way I've seen this used is in writing custom PHP extensions in C, and this is not something I'm interested in tackling for a quick-fix solution. I've looked at Redis and Memcached, but these don't seem to be designed for large data sets, and don't seem to run on Windows.

Any ideas on how I can filter this data efficiently? An example query might be 'give me all events that were active between 1 Jan 2010 and 15 Mar 2013'.

Comment: Use something like memcache, apc, wincache, etc to store it in memory. The only issue is if you want to query it you'll have to essentially pull it out of memory and then search through the data that way.

Comment: Care to share what "government organization" you work for?

Comment: Depending on the JSON data, if I was you, I'd transform it to a SQLite database and use it until the final database get ready. :)

Comment: How about MongoDB? Data is stored in the database in json format, and there are a range of admin interfaces available: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/, or you can query it using a REST interface over http. Queries can be created in Javascript and passed to the database - not very fast but it does work, and easy to set up from your existing data.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Turns out they just might have a database ready for me...so the pressure is off on this one.